# Why won't homebrew update PHP 7.1 to a stable version?

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I recently ran `brew update && brew upgrade` then `php -v` and I got:

```
PHP 7.1.0alpha2 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2017 16:01:17) ( NTS )
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but it keeps pulling in alpha-2 instead of the [current 7.1.0](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/blob/master/Formula/php71.rb).

Any idea as to why I'm stuck on PHP 7.1 alpha?